# Spring scoped-proxy transactions are fine via JPA but not commiting via JDBC

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I have a situation where I have to handle multiple clients in one app and each client has separate database. To support that I'm using Spring custom scope, quite similar to the built in request scope. A user authenticates in each request and can set context client ID based passed credentials. The scoping itself seems to be working properly.

So I used my custom scope to create a scoped-proxy for my `DataSource` to support a diffrent database per client. And I get connections to proper databases.

Than I created a scoped-proxy for `EntityManagerFactory` to use JPA. And this part also looks OK.

Than I added a scoped-proxy for `PlatformTransactionManager` for declarative transaction management. I use `@Transactional` on my service layer and it gets propagated nicely to my SpringData powered repository layer.

All is fine and works correctly as long a s I use only JPA. I can even switch context to a diffrent client within the request (I use ThreadLocals under the hood) and transactions to both databases are handled correctly.

The problems start when I try to use `JDBCTempate` in one of my custom repositiries. Than at first glance all looks OK too, as no exceptions are thrown. But when I check the database for the objects I thought I inserted with my custom JDBC-based repository the're not there!

I know for sure I can use JPA and JDBC together by declaring only `JpaTransactionManager` and passing both the `DataSource` and `EntityManagerFactory` to it - I checked it and without the scoped-proxies and it works.

**So the question is how to make JDBC work together with JPA using the `JpaTransactionManager` when I have scoped-proxied the `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory` and `PlatformTransactionManager` beans?** I remind that using only JPA works perfectly, but adding plain JDBC into the mix is not working.

---

**UPDATE1:** And one more thing: all readonly (SELECT) operations work fine with JDBC too - only writes (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) end up not commited or rolledback.

---

**UPDATE2:** As @Tomasz suggested I've removed scoped proxy from `EntityManagerFactory` and `PlatformTransactionManager` as those are indeed not needed and provide more confusion than anything else.

The real problem seems to be switching the scope context **within** a transaction. The `TransactionSynchronizationManager` bounds transactional resources (i.e. `EMF` or `DS`) to thread at transaction start. It has the ability to unwrap the scoped proxy, so it binds the actual instance of the resource from the scope active at the time of starting a transaction. Then when I change the context within a transaction it all gets messed up.

It seems like I need to suspend the active transaction and store aside the current transaction context to be able to clear it upon entering another scope to make Spring think it's not inside a transaction any more and to force it create one for the new scope when needed. And then when leaving the scope I'd have to restore the previously suspended transaction. Unfortunatelly I was unable to come up with a working implementation yet. Any hints appreciated.

---

And below is some code of mine, but it's pretty standard, except for the scoped-proxies.

The `DataSource`:

```
<!-- provides database name based on client context -->
<bean id="clientDatabaseNameProvider"
    class="com.example.common.spring.scope.ClientScopedNameProviderImpl"
    c:clientScopeHolder-ref="clientScopeHolder"
    p:databaseName="${base.db.name}" />

<!-- an extension of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource that 
    uses proper database URL based on database name given by above provider -->
<bean id="jpaDataSource" scope="client"
    class="com.example.common.spring.datasource.MysqlDbInitializingDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${mysql.driver}"
    p:url="${mysql.url}"
    p:databaseNameProvider-ref="clientDatabaseNameProvider"
    p:username="${mysql.username}"
    p:password="${mysql.password}"
    p:defaultAutoCommit="false"
    p:connectionProperties="sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

The `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:database="MYSQL"
    p:generateDdl="true"
    p:showSql="true" />

<util:properties id="jpaProperties">
    <!-- omitted for readability -->
</util:properties>

<bean id="jpaDialect"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="com.example.model.core"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource"
    p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
    p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProperties" />
```

The `PlatformTracsactionManager`:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="false" mode="proxy"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Did you try to debug org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#doGetConnection to see what's going on?

Comment: @mrembisz yes I did; it all seems quite fine there; the `DataSource` is bound to thread using `TransactionSynchronizationManager`; I'm not entirerly sure if the registered transaction synchronization callback is than called correctly as there are so many calls to `TransactionSynchronizationManager` in a single request that I get confused after two dozens :/

Comment: 1. I don't think custom scope is required for `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `JpaTransactionManager` as they both simply delegate to `DataSource` (which is proxied). 2. Are you aware of [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) - doesn't it handle the exact same use case you have? 3. If you enable `org.springframework.transaction` logger doesn't it show something suspicious? 4. If you combine JPA and JDBC updates in one transactions, both aren't committed?